# Send data with jsonp onclick

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jsonp

I've been trying to figure out how to use jsonp in my situation, but no luck. This counts the clicks and on each click it writes the name and location to a txt file.

```
<script>
var count1 = 0;
function countClicks1() {
count1 = count1 + 1;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = count1;
}
function doAjax()
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "phpfile.php",
   data: "name=name&location=location",
    success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
}

document.write('</p>');
document.write('<button onclick="countClicks1(); doAjax();">Count</button>');
document.write('</p>');
document.write('<p id="p1">0</p>');
</script>
```

This is the php file phpfile.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $name);
fwrite($fh, $location);   
fclose($fh);
?>
```

If these two files are on the same domain everything is fine. But if I want to do the same for another domain, it won't work. I would like to send the same information with jsonp to the phpfile.php. I know it should be with GET but I just can't figure out how.

Comment: You may use getJSON : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Please stop using document.write. It makes my eyes hurt...

Comment: Off-topic: About the PHP code - are you sure that `fopen($myFile, 'w')` is correct? That will open a file for **writing**, and all previous content will be overwritten. I think you want to do `fopen($myFile, 'a')` instead. That opens the file for **appending**.

Comment: i m just using the txt file for testing. what should I use instead of document.write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your php file does not output anything, so I wouldn't call this JSONP at all. JSONP is a method for getting JSON data using a GET request that returns a chunk of Javascript that can be loaded using a `<SCRIPT>` tag.

For doing JSONP yourself, you'll have to do something like this:

```
<?php
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$location = $_GET['location'];
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $name);
fwrite($fh, $location);   
fclose($fh);
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
?>

<?php echo $callback; ?>("Message from the server");
```

Then perform the call something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://server/phpfile.php?name=FOO&location=BAR&callback=?",
          function(message) {
              alert(msg);
          });
```

**BUT...** Since you don't actually return any data from the server, you could just as well just fake-load an image with the correct URL. That would greatly reduce the overhead.

Comment: how do I return data from the server? I want to check if the user is logged in or not